# How to write a query to both include and exclude tags in RediSearch?

Tags: syntax, include, redisearch

I want to include and exclude a set of tags in **RediSearch** queries. How can I do it?

The query below is what I am trying to do:

```
FT.SEARCH permits "@tags:{DE | EN | -(NO | EE)}"
```

It gives an error: `(error) Syntax error at offset 17 near 'EN'`

What would be the syntax to include and exclude tags in **RediSearch**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get away with something like:

```
FT.SEARCH permits "@tags:{DE|EN} -@tags:{NO|EE}"
```

Comment: Could you possible give any idea where to find answers for questions like this? I tried to find documentation for Redis Search but as far as I see there is no single formal place where I can read/view docs with enough details and examples?

Comment: We're planning on adding more examples to the docs - this kind of query definitely belongs there.

Comment: I think that the right answer should be something like this: ``` FT.SEARCH permits "@tags:{ DE } @tags:{ EN } -@tags:{ NO } -@tags:{ EE } " ```